# iOS - Updating label during animation transition?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a UIView on the screen that contains a few labels. I am trying to have a transition where flips the view, and as soon as I am half way through the nimation I want to be able to update the labels. How Can I achieve this?

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.myView
                          duration:.7
                           options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromBottom
                        animations:^{
                            // It doesn't update the labels here, until I scoll the tableview (containing the view)
                            //[self.myView update];
                                            }
                        completion:^(BOOL finished){
                            // It doesn't look nice here because it doesn't look smooth, the label flashes and changes after the animation is complete
                            //[self.myView update];
                        }];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that I had shouldRasterize enabled which was not allowing the content to be updated during an animaton. Solution was to turn off rasterization before the animation and turn it back on after animation completion.

The reason why I didn't get rid of rasterization is that the view is inside a tableView, and rasterization still helps while scrolling through the tableView.

```
self.layer.shouldRasterize = NO;

[UIView transitionWithView:self
              duration:animationDuration
               options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromBottom
            animations:^{/*update the content here, I did it outside of the transition method though*/}
            completion:^(BOOL finished){
                if (finished)
                {
                           self.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
                }
            }];
```